# Angular - Array is not shown in mat-table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

In the function, the string is split into an array. Each word gets send to the server, from there I get some information about the word back. This I save into an array. The problem I have is that if I go through the array with *ngFor in the HTML document I get all the entries back but in the mat-table, it isn't shown. I don't get an error just the data is not shown.

```
sendText(){
 this.words=[];

this.stringArray = this.sentence.split(" "); 
 console.log(this.stringArray);

 for(let i=0;i<this.stringArray.length ;i++){ 

   this.httpService.sendText(this.stringArray[i]).subscribe((res) => {
     
    this.result = res;
  console.log(this.result.words);
  this.b.wort = this.result.words[0].wort;
  this.b.definition = this.result.words[0].definition;
  this.b.wortart = this.result.words[0].wortart;

   this.words.push(this.b);
  this.b = this.getemptyObject();
 
  
  });}   console.log(this.words);    this.sentence = "";}
```

HTML

```
    <div *ngFor="let word of words"> 
{{word.wort}},{{word.definition}}, {{word.wortart}}

</div>

<table mat-table [dataSource]="words" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Word Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="wort">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Wort </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let word"> {{word.wort}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Wortdtype Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="wortart">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Wortart </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let word"> {{word.wortart}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this question on this [Reddit Thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/m82u8t/adding_a_item_in_mat_table_the_ui_does_not_refresh/).

According to "@spacechimp" (the person who answered the question), you need to update the entire array for the MatTable to detect the changes.

Something like this:

```js
this.words.push(this.b);
this.words = [...this.words]; // <--- Update the whole array with its own data
```

Even though this is *a* solution, it is a rather expensive way of doing this for large arrays, so I encourage you to find other ways to optimize this.